# How to choose the right garden plants around the building wall and dry wells

Tags: plant-recommendations, landscaping, drainage, urban-gardening, foundation

If trees/shrubs are planted too close to a house, the roots can damage the foundation

Only two to three feet is available from the building wall on both the sides of the building and dry wells with the depth of 5 feet is around the building for drainage water.

Some kind of Grass or flower would help absorb water around the building foundation and I'd like the plants root doesn't affect my building foundation as well

Could someone please help me with right types of grass or flower for me to plant ?

Any suggestion in retain wall construction and landscape design is also welcome. Here is something I have in mind

[image]

Comment: Great pictures, that will help us, what about location and what is available to buy near you?

Comment: @kevinskio - There's no ground available for buying unfortunately.  There's no ground left on front and rear of the building. To the south there is 2.5 ft vacant space for 60 feet length and to the north of the building we have 3.5 ft vacanct space for 60 feet length.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, Where are you located and what kind of plants are available to buy near you?  Or were you going to grow them from seeds or ???

Comment: I'm located in India and I'm happy to grow it from seeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all consider the [climatic conditions](http://rftp.com/climate-classification-of-india.html).

### Then the functional demands:

Should the plants shield the house from wind, rain, or sun? Do you like the sound of the wind in the leaves? The depths of roots. Do you want to attract birds or butterflies?

### Then architectonical demands:

Do you prefer shaped bushes positioned with equal distance or a more wild looking garden? Which colours and style matches your house and garden. Do you want to create a certain mood around your house?
Make some drawings to test your design only using fantasy bushes and flowers.

### Now, consider wild species native to your local area:

Do some of them fulfill your demands?
Native species should always be the first choice for easy growing and harmony with nature.

### Take a walk in the neighborhood:

Which species are doing well in your local area? Usually you can ask the owner for seeds or cuttings, and experience with the roots.

Earlier I have had [Umbrella Bamboo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fargesia_murielae) close to my house without troubles from the roots, and I think many bamboos are safe without deep roots.
Absorbs water well but also need watering in dry periods.

Personally, I would choose [Mexican Lime](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/112190/citrus-%25C3%2597-aurantiifolia-(f)-lime-mexican-lime/details) (comes true from seeds, easy to shape, excellent in dry conditions), [Pomegranates](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/67011/punica-granatum-var-nana/details) (easy to shape, available in even very small editions, easy propagation from seeds), and perhaps [Opuntia](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/11871/opuntia-ficus-indica/details) (dry conditions, slow growing).

Comment: Thanks for the climate map :) and plant suggestion...I'll check that out , I'd like the plant to take lots of water and evaporate as much as possible and the roots not affect the building foundation.